# Google Oauth error - Popup automatically closed in React

Tags: reactjs, google-cloud-platform, google-oauth

Everyone!

I'm having serious problem with Google OAuth2 and React.

Currently I'm using @react-oauth/google module for google authendication.

I've deployed my current codebase on 2 server.

One is staging and one is production.

Here are links

https://www.spresssong.com/customer/auth/signin

https://spresssong-staging-front.herokuapp.com/customer/auth/signin

I've added above two urls to Authorized JavaScript origins and Authorized redirect URIs in credential page.

The problem is when click signin with google button, I'm getting this error with popup window.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XgNpM.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IofBA.png)

the source code are same on two server.

google signin is working on this site.

https://spresssong-staging-front.herokuapp.com

But not working on this site.

https://www.spresssong.com

I've used this hook for google auth.

```
  const googleLogin = useGoogleLogin({
    onSuccess: async tokenResponse => {
      const userInfo = await axios
        .get('https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/userinfo', {
          headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${tokenResponse.access_token}` },
        })
        .then(res => res.data);

      
      let role = '';
      if(window.location.pathname.split('/')[1] === 'customer'){
        role = 'Customer';
      }
      else if(window.location.pathname.split('/')[1] === 'artist') {
        role = 'Artist';
      }
      else if(window.location.pathname.split('/')[1] === 'finance') {
        role = 'Finance';
      }
      else if(window.location.pathname.split('/')[1] === 'idol') {
        role = 'Idol';
      }
      OAuthSignin({email: userInfo.email, role})
    },
    onError: (e) => {
      console.log(e)
    },
    onNonOAuthError: (err) => {
      console.log(err);
    },
  });
```

My question is when onNonOAuthError callback normally called?

Please help me.

Thank you

Comment: Hi James, your prod site is unreachable for me. Regarding the popup on prod, is it possible that it got blocked by a browser extension of yours? Does this problem persist in incognito mode?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Macak.
I've just updated link of my prod site.
From https://spresssong.com to https://www.spresssong.com
Is there any relation with it?

Comment: So I tried to sign up with the production URL(spresssong.com) & it kinda of hanged trying to sign up, meanwhile using the dev one I got this: `Error 400: redirect_uri_mismatch`

Comment: Hi James, have you solved your issue? I got stuck in very same point: React, GSI, popup window close error. And only on production site. When trying the same code on localhost, it works. The problem was in Cross Origin Opener Policy that must be setup to 'same-origin-allow-popups'.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Fide. Can you share me full coe part for 'same-origin-allow-popups'?

Comment: Any update regarding this issue?
I've got stuck with this issue for about 2 months :(
I think this issue relating with using 2 domains for one site.
Seems Google auth service preventing this action?